# INSERT a comment to youtube by API PHP

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to insert a youtube video comment to a particular video but it keeps on redirecting and inserting my text many times to the video.please help me solve this problem and here's my code and I use [google api library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

```
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();



$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'XXX';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXX';


$VIDEO_ID = 'XXX';

$TEXT = 'hi';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        while(strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])){
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
            }
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        header('Location: ' . $redirect);
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
      $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    }
    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
        try {
            $commentSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_CommentSnippet();
            $commentSnippet->setTextOriginal($TEXT);
            $topLevelComment = new Google_Service_YouTube_Comment();
            $topLevelComment->setSnippet($commentSnippet);
            $commentThreadSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_CommentThreadSnippet();
            $commentThreadSnippet->setTopLevelComment($topLevelComment);
            $commentThread = new Google_Service_YouTube_CommentThread();
            $commentThread->setSnippet($commentThreadSnippet);
            $commentThreadSnippet->setVideoId($VIDEO_ID);
            $videoCommentInsertResponse = $youtube->commentThreads->insert('snippet', $commentThread);
        } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
            $htmlBody = sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
        } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
            $htmlBody = sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
        }
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    }
```

Comment: How many times does it insert the text? Does it insert the text the same number of times every time you try it?

Comment: it is doing infinite times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a comment in a YouTube video using the You Tube Data API the`***commentThreads.insert***` method should be used. I am not able to find that method in your code. Please take a look at this [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert) to perform this action.

Hope that helps!!

Comment: I used the method  $videoCommentInsertResponse = $youtube->commentThreads->insert('snippet', $commentThread);